# Where can I find the list of non-reentrant functions provided in gnu libc?

Tags: c, multithreading, glibc

I am now porting an single-threaded library to support multi-threads, and I need the whole list of functions that use local static or global variables.

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: General advice: Treat all functions as _not_ reentrant unless stated otherwise in the manual page.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That advice, if applied to the glibc manual, would yield a very large number of false positives; the manual simply isn't written that way. (And the term people want is "thread-safe", not "reentrant" -- they mean quite different things. reentrancy is a concept that long preceded threads or any other sort of concurrency.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. I think I got your point, but this is not what I am looking for. I wrote a scripts to search the man pages and collect all the function() with the function_r() equivalent exists. I think this is what I need.

Comment: @longbowk No. reentrancy means that the function can be called from an asynchronous interrupt while the function is active. Consider a function with a critical section. It is thread safe but not reentrant.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes. You are right. I just thought the example you show me and are going to corrent the question I asked.Then found you already answered me. Thank you very much. Then what I am looking for is non-thread-safe,Not non-reentrant. Then Joachimpileborg's advice is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the manual page for each function you use ... the non-thread-safe ones will be identified as such, and the manual page will mention a thread safe version when there is one (e.g., `readdir_r`). You could extract the list by running a script over the man pages.

Edit: Although my answer has been accepted, I fear that it is inaccurate and possibly dangerous. For example, while strerror_r mentions that it is a thread safe version of strerror, strerror itself says nothing about thread safety ... what it says instead is "the string might be overwritten", which merely *implies* that it isn't thread-safe. So you need to search for at least "might be overwritten" as well as "thread", but there's no guarantee that even that will be complete.

Comment: This is indeed what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @longbowk Please see my added caveat.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I see your caveat. But is there an exception that a function() without function_r() equivalent use a local static or global varibles?

Comment: @longbowk I *think* there are no such exceptions because so much effort has gone into making the library thread safe but, again, "there's no guarantee".

Comment: OK. Got it. I'll search the manual which says "overwritten" , "thread". etc. And check whether there are more functions need to be added to the list.

Comment: @longbowk tmpnam and tmpnam_r say nothing about threads but do refer (incorrectly, as I've noted), to "non-reentrant" and instead of "overwritten" tmpnam says "a pointer to an internal static string, which might be modified by subsequent calls". But at least there's the _r, which probably does cover everything.

Answer (score 1):

Its always a good idea to know if a particular function is reentrant or not, but you must also consider the situation when you may call several reentrant functions from a shared piece of code from multiple threads, which could also lead to problems when using shared data.

So, if you have any data shared between threads, the data must be "protected" irregardless of the fact that the functions being called are reentrant.

Consider the following function:

```
void yourFunc(CommonObject *o)
{
    /* This function is NOT thread safe */
    reentrant_func1(o->propertyA);
    reentrant_func2(o->propertyA);
}
```

If this function is not mutex protected, you will get undesired behavior in a multithreaded application, irregardless of the fact that func1 and func2 are reentrant.

Comment: Thanks. I have thought of it. Thank you.